# Drawable Animation in a ListView moves when another item is selected

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to display an animation on specific items in a List View. The way animation is started is when you tap on an item in the list view, press a button to initiate some process, the animation starts.

Everything seem to be working fine. I was able to start the animation based on the selected item. But here is the weird behavior, as soon as I tap another item in the list view, the animation moves along with it.

The animation should stick to the previously selected item. And if I tap on the button while the 2nd item is selected, then it should start the animation on this item.

The List View has an adapter but the meat of this adapter is on the GetBindableView method which basically just sets the background color (nothing fancy):

```
protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object source, int templateId)
    {
        var view = base.GetBindableView(convertView, source, templateId);
        var item = source as Inspection;
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.IsSelected)
            {
                view.SetBackgroundColor((Color)Helper.ToMvxColor(Const.ListViewSelectorHexColor));
            }
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Here's the xml for the List View:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
     android:id="@+id/listView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Inspections; SelectedItem SelectedInspection; Visibility Visibility(PendingInsListViewVisible)"
     local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/template_listview"
     style="@style/listview" />
```

And here is the template:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="@style/listview_item">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/caching_anim"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                style="@style/caching_image" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                style="@style/form_label.spacer" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonLock"
                    local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(BooleanValueToBoolean(Locked))"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_lock"
                    style="@style/toggle_lock_image" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonUnLock"
                    local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(FinishedButNotLocked)"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_unlock"
                    style="@style/toggle_lock_image" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/blankImage"
                    local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(If(FinishedButNotLocked, false, true))"
                    android:src="@drawable/blank"
                    style="@style/toggle_lock_image" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                local:MvxBind="Text MarkerLabel"
                android:gravity="center"
                style="@style/listview_item.marker" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

The animation is being done on the ImageView with the Id "caching_anim".

Has anyone tried or has seen this behavior? What should I do to make the animation stick to the specific item? What am I missing here? Let me know if more clarification is required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you make a small recording with http://recordit.co/ to understand how the animation is "moving" with the new item?

Comment: @AndreiN.Sorry for the delayed response. I've been tied up with other stuff. What I mean with this is that when you select row 1, tap a button and this will start the animation on that row. you then select row 2. The animation running in row 1 disappears and it is now in row 2.

Comment: I can't help without knowing how you update caching_anim

Comment: @AndreiN. yeah, it's more complicated than I've explained. I'm going in a different direction which I think would work for me. Thank a lot for taking your time in trying to help me. :)